# Android WebView with two MustBe functions and integration, app development

Tags: android, web-applications, android-webview

I am doing Android WebView app with Studio. I have two functions(See COde 1, COde2) But I could not get two different functions to get working both at the same app(together, in the code). **How can I Integrate these two codes so that they both work?**

My first days of using the Android Studio to make an application, so any help would be really great.

**COde 1** to attach/upload images/files, browser event(HTML:input type=file):

```
  mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    assert mywebView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        //For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FCR);
        }
        // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FCR);
        }
        //For Android 4.1+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
        }
        //For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
            if(mUMA != null){
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                File photoFile = null;
                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if(photoFile != null){
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                }else{
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if(takePictureIntent != null){
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            }else{
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

**COde 2** to play videos in my App (Code that is promising, as playing videos is almost impossible in a Webview App?). After 3 days of searching:

```
//video start
    // Save the web view
    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // Initialize the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient and set event handlers
    View nonVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
    ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
    //noinspection all
    View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_loading_video, null); // Your own view, read class comments
    webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView) // See all available constructors...
    {
        // Subscribe to standard events, such as onProgressChanged()...
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            // Your code...
        }
    };
    webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
        {
            // Your code to handle the full-screen change, for example showing and hiding the title bar. Example:
            if (fullscreen)
            {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    //noinspection all
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    //noinspection all
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    // Call private class InsideWebViewClient
    webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());

    // Navigate anywhere you want, but consider that this classes have only been tested on YouTube's mobile site
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
```

ANSWER is AFTER this:

```
  // Your code...
    }
 (inside WebChromeClient() functions here)
```

Should delete this now